# How to increase the size of my code in my eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to increase the size of my code in my eclipse 4.3 editor ..
I tried pressing ctrl + "+" but it doesnt work. 
so how to increase the size of my code in my eclipse editor for me to see it ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24621/how-to-increase-font-size-of-eclipse-globally

Preferences, navigate to General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

go to:

window -> preferences -> General -> appareance -> Colors and fonts -> Java -> Java editor Text (double click)